# How do you call a function inside of another functions for loop, while passing an array through the function?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm getting an error message saying that there is no matching function for the call to my function (validateData) that i am calling inside of a for loop of another function(inputData), even though i have declared the function and have a definition for the function.

I have gone into a tutor on campus to have them help me with the parameters of the function, and now that the parameters are fixed, the function is not calling when i call it, giving me an error message.

```
//Declare global constants
const int STUDENTS = 3;
const int NONNUMERIC_INFO = 9;
const int NUMERIC_INFO = 2;
const int COURSES = 3;
const int TESTS_and_CNG = 6;

//Declare function prototypes
void inputData();

void validateData(string nonNumeric1[STUDENTS][NUMERIC_INFO], int numeric1[STUDENTS][NUMERIC_INFO], double numeric2[STUDENTS][COURSES][TESTS_and_CNG], int i);

void validateData(string nonNumeric1[STUDENTS][NUMERIC_INFO], int numeric1[STUDENTS][NUMERIC_INFO], double numeric2[STUDENTS][COURSES][TESTS_and_CNG], int i, int j);

void validateData(string nonNumeric1[][NUMERIC_INFO], int numeric1[STUDENTS][NUMERIC_INFO], double numeric2[STUDENTS][COURSES][TESTS_and_CNG], int i, int j, int k);
```

inside the main function, it calls the inputData function

```
//Declaring arrays (inside inputData function definition 
string nonNumeric1[STUDENTS][NONNUMERIC_INFO];
int numeric1[STUDENTS][NUMERIC_INFO];
double numeric2[STUDENTS][COURSES][TESTS_and_CNG];
```

```
   //Outer loop on students
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        getline(fin, nonNumeric1[i][1]); //Name
        getline(fin, nonNumeric1[i][2]); //ID
        fin >> numeric1[i][0]; // Age
        fin.ignore();
        getline(fin, nonNumeric1[i][3]); //Address
        fin >> numeric1[i][1]; //Years
        fin.ignore();
        getline(fin, nonNumeric1[i][4]); //Phone
        getline(fin, nonNumeric1[i][5]); //SSN
        validateData(nonNumeric1, numeric1, numeric2, i); //error message here

        //Middle loop on course
        for(int j = 6; j < 9; j++)
        {
            getline(fin, nonNumeric1[i][j]); //Course
            validateData(nonNumeric1, numeric1, numeric2, i, j); //error here

            //Inner loop on tests
            for(int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
            {
                fin >> numeric2[i][j][k]; //Grade
                fin.ignore();
                validateData(nonNumeric1, numeric1, numeric2, i, j, k); //error here too
                numGrade(nonNumeric1, numeric1, numeric2, i, j , k);
                letGrade(numeric2, i, j , k);
                comments(numeric2, i, j, k);
                report(nonNumeric1, numeric1, numeric2, int i, int j, int k);
            }
```

```
//Function definition
void validateData(string nonNumeric1[][NONNUMERIC_INFO], int numeric1[][NUMERIC_INFO], double numeric2[][COURSES][TESTS_and_CNG], int i)
{
    //if statements to validate all data that only uses the i variable 
}
void validateData(string nonNumeric1[][NONNUMERIC_INFO], int numeric1[][NUMERIC_INFO], double numeric2[][COURSES][TESTS_and_CNG], int i, int j)
{
    //if statements to validate all data that only uses the i and j variables 
}
void validateData(string nonNumeric1[][NONNUMERIC_INFO], int numeric1[][NUMERIC_INFO], double numeric2[][COURSES][TESTS_and_CNG], int i, int j, int k)
{
    //if statements to validate all data that only uses the i,j and k variables 
}
```

the error message is "error: no matching function for call to 'validateData(std::__cxx11::string [3][9], int [3][2], double [3][3][6], int&')"
the error also happens on the other validateData function calls

Comment: Back up your code and build yourself a [mcve]. If you can't figure out what the problem is once you've removed everything in the program you don't need to have in the program in order to get the error, edit the question and add the MCVE. If making the MCVE helps you find the error, congratulations! You didn't need us. Either self answer the question or delete it.

Comment: ive already tried commenting out everything else that i dont need and it gives me the same error

Comment: Sounds like you're just about at the MCVE then. Formalize it and post it.

Comment: whats wrong with this post already? the MCVE that i have is still a pretty heavy amount of code, im pretty sure that i have included everything i need for someone to answer the question, or at least explain the error to me.

Comment: 1) The 'M' stands for "Minimal", so if it's *"still a pretty heavy amount of code",* you probably aren't there yet. 2) The fact that your code has both `TESTS_and_CNG` and `TEST_and_CNG` is a great big red flag.

Comment: i hadn't noticed that, but it is supposed to be TESTS_and_CNG, just changed it in the code, still getting same error message

Answer (score -2, accepted):

validdateData func needs string, int, ....

You should declare like this

```
void validateData(string param1, int param2, double param3, int i);
```

Your func need not to know your variable looks like.

And you declared your array,

```
string nonNumeric1[STUDENTS][NONNUMERIC_INFO];
```

But you tried to call

```
nonNumeric1[STUDENTS][NONNUMERIC_INFO]
```

Actually, it's illegal access. That memory is not your assigned array.

Comment: if you want to call validateData,
How about try this,

Code:
void validateData(string param1, int param2, double param3, int i);

Call:
validateData(some string, some int, some double, some int);

Comment: ahh yes, i had NUMERIC_INFO inside the nonNumeric1 array, instead of NONUMERIC_INFO, that fixed the error! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There's a mismatch between the arguments and parameters.

you declare

```
string nonNumeric1[STUDENTS][NONNUMERIC_INFO];

void validateData(string nonNumeric1[STUDENTS][NUMERIC_INFO], int numeric1[STUDENTS][NUMERIC_INFO], double numeric2[STUDENTS][COURSES][TESTS_and_CNG], int i);
```

but call

> validateData(nonNumeric1, numeric1, numeric2, i, j); //error here

the parameter expected has a dimension of "NUMERIC_INFO" but you pass in an array of size "NONNUMERIC_INFO"